# Auto Trace Installation Error in QGIS 3.8

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, installation, trace

My QGIS 3.8 doesn't support Auto Trace 1.0.6 or 1.0.7. My pc has a 64bit Windows 10. How can I solve it?

[image: Auto Trace Installation Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find Snapping Option from the Project tab or enable the Snapping Toolbar from the Toolbars under the View tab.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The AutoTrace plugin can only be installed in versions 2.x of QGIS so you can not install it in a version 3.x installation.

The functionality of the AutoTrace plugin is now available on the [Snapping toolbar](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#setting-the-snapping-tolerance-and-search-radius) (you will probably need to enable this).